# vim syntax highlighting for partial overlap (*not* nested) regex matches?

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I have a long .vim file of arbitrary strings to be highlighted. I have it working, except that where two expressions overlap, the first is highlighted, and the second is not. For example, two of the lines are...

```
the third part
part of the trilogy
```

... and in the phrase "the third part of the trilogy," only the first three words are properly highlighted, because the second line is not matched. Is there any to match both lines, so the whole phrase is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

It's not at all clear what you are trying to match here but

```
third.*\n.*the
```

will hilight across lines.

If you want to highlight third AND part then

```
third.*\n*part will work.
```

Have a look here http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines for the other other options as I don't totally understand why the \n needs a * after it to complete the match.

Comment: I'm not trying to match across lines. I'm trying to match overlapping strings within a line. The problem is that the regex expressions currently get in each others' way.